# How do I use Check with Table to skip results that contain error messages

Tags: warning-messages, procedural-programming, table

I want to run an iteration where at each step I check whether I obtain an error message, and if I do, I want to not store that result and move on to the next iteration instead. Here's an example of how it's working using a Do Loop:

```
Do[Quiet[If[Check[i^0, error] == error, Continue[]]]; Print[i], {i, {1, 0, 2, 0, 1}}]; 
1
2
1
```

Now, I would like to do something similar using Table instead, and I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Table[If[Check[i^0, err] == err, Nothing, i], {i, {1, 0, 2, 0, 1}}]
```

but this does not work. The output I get is:

```
{If[1 == err, Nothing, i], If[1 == err, Nothing, i], If[1 == err, Nothing, i]}
```

If I try doing something that does not involve the function Check, like this:

```
Table[If[i == 2, Nothing, i], {i, 1, 6}]
{1, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

that does work. Is there a way to make Table work with Check in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `===`

```
data = Table[If[Check[i^0, err] === err, Nothing, i], {i, {1, 0, 2, 0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should have used `===` in your `Do` loop also. But there because of `Continue` you did not notice as it was starting new loop each time.

You can write the Table like this also, which is little bit more clear.

```
data = Table[z = Quiet@Check[i^0, err]; 
  If[z === err, Nothing, i], {i, {1, 0, 2, 0, 1}}]
```